# PHP cURL not working on other sites

Tags: php, curl, web, xampp

I'm a novice programmer in PHP. Last week I read about cURL that capture my attention to study it. first, I copy and paste codes posted on different blogs and it goes run good like my code below.

```
<?php
$handle=curl_init('http://www.google.co.kr/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($handle);
echo $content;
?>
```

BUT WHY I CAN'T cURL the website

http://www.todayhumor.co.kr/

since that, i am using same code above it outputs

[image]

Looking for your positive response guys. thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you Sandeep for editing my grammar..

Comment: Check your server’s error log, _as the message already told you to do_.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `curl_exec($handle)` you should close the session with `curl_close($handle)`. Maybe you tried so many times and now it doesn't work anymore, because you have so many open sessions on your local server. I would add that line to your code, restart xampp and try again.

**Edit:**
The server rejects requests without a valid user-agent. Add a user-agent to your request: `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36');` this worked for me

Comment: I restart twice my Xampp but still same output.

Comment: I tried also HTML DOM PARSEL but still doesn't work on this website..
<?php
include_once '/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.todayhumor.co.kr/');
echo $html;
?>

Comment: Try to output additional information about the error. What does it say?
`echo curl_errno($handle);`
`echo curl_error($handle);`
`var_dump(curl_getinfo($handle));`

Comment: echo curl_errno($handle);
& 
 echo curl_error($handle);

there outputs is both 0 and 

var_dump(curl_getinfo($handle));

has an output of

Comment: 00array(26) { ["url"]=> string(28) "http://www.todayhumor.co.kr/" ["content_type"]=> string(29) "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" ["http_code"]=> int(500) ["header_size"]=> int(398) ["request_size"]=> int(59) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.625) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.234) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.234) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(1226) [ . . . . . . . . . and so on

Comment: The server rejects requests without a valid user-agent. Add a user-agent to your request: `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36');` this worked for me.

Comment: Finally, This worked!. Thank you so much st2erw2od! Hopefully I pay back you soon.:-)